# Can I change the color of the Index in the right of a TableView?

Tags: xcode, text, colors, indexing, tableview

Can we change the color of the index column of a table view that appear in the right (for example: A B C...)? Not the header, only the right column.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check the method `sectionIndexColor` in header of UITableView.